# Confused with the behavior of FragmentManager popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments,

First Fragment using FragmentTransaction replace method to display, it works fine, then i want to display Second Fragment and hide First Fragment, so i used

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(FirstFragment).add(this.containerID, SecondFragment, fragmentTagString);
```

and observe life cycle, but found it is wired, below log is the code above

```
05-28 13:53:44.986: I/Fragment(31490): First Fragment onCreate
05-28 13:53:44.986: I/Fragment(31490): Second Fragment onCreate
05-28 13:53:44.986: I/Fragment(31490): Second Fragment onCreateView
05-28 13:53:44.991: I/Fragment(31490): First Fragment onResume
05-28 13:53:44.991: I/Fragment(31490): Second Fragment onResume
```

Why First Fragment doing "onCreate" and "onResume" while hide()?

Then i pressed back button on device, override the back event

```
/* Back pressed */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!this.appFragmentController.popFragment()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

These part is check fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(), if > 0, do fragmentManager.popBackStack(), then i also observe the log of life cycle, and i got

```
05-28 13:54:34.076: I/Fragment(31490): First Fragment onPause
05-28 13:54:34.081: I/Fragment(31490): Second Fragment onPause
```

OK, now i am very confused with the life cycle, in my knowledge, when hide a Fragment should not do onCreate and onResume, it should do "onPause" doesn't it? And after popBackStack it should not do onPause, can someone tell me how it works?

p.s.
I know when you use Fragment B to replace Fragment A, then do popBackStack(), it will remove B and Add A, so when i did add Fragment B and hide fragment A, then do popBackStack(), it should be remove B and show A, right?